# Call a method in Activity of BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I transfer context into a Specific Activity in onReceive(）of BroadcastReceiver, like `MyActivity ma = (MyActivity) context;`. I want to call a method in Activity, but when I transfer context, it has this error: `ClassCastException error`. Before, in another project, I transferred the service without problem. Why does it give an error？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because `context` variable in `onReceive` method  [(docs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) is `The Context in which the receiver is running`.  ( you can't cast it to `activity` because receiver is running in application context, I think.)

You can organize communication between application components via `handlers` or via broadcasting custom intents.